# Express path error Cannot GET / for express npm run dev

Tags: node.js, express

I am having trouble loading up the server and having the html file load. I am running a npm run dev. and this is what got changed in there:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
```

This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');



app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'html')));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server started on port ${PORT}'));
```

Any help is much appreciated since I am a newbie at express.

Answer (score 0):

You must use nodemon and then the command you whant to run, in your case it would be:
`nodemon node index.js`